# jquery-nice-select with angular cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am trying to use [jquery-nice-select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-nice-select) plugin of Jquery with angular cli. can someone please suggest the best approach for it.

Installed Jquery and Jquery-nice-select via npm. imported jquery using code

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

don't know how should jquery-nice-select need to be imported. tried

```
$('select').niceSelect();
```

it's throwing an error niceSelect() is not not a function

Comment: Where do you get stuck ?

Comment: please see question, have updated it.

Comment: Did you follow all the steps required to [use a 3rd party library](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-third-party-lib) with angular and the cli?

Comment: yup, i have seen this, but i am bit confused. jquery-nice-select exposes the function niceselect(). this function needs to be applied on select element itself. in jquery $('select').niceSelect(); is being used, but how the same should be done in angular?

Comment: replace `import $ from 'jquery';` with `declare var $: any;` If you added the proper script to the angular-cli.json file, this should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for record, putting answer here.

as mentioned by [@peinearydevelopment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1874522/peinearydevelopment), just include js flies in angular-cli.json scripts sections and declare them. for Jquery

```
declare var $: any;
```